# Ubuntu 13.10 apache keeps giving this error while accessing website

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, lamp

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10. I followed [this guide](http://linuxg.net/install-lamp-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/) (most of it) to setup LAMP. Then I was getting this error about

> Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Which I solved by adding a line `ServerName localhost` to the `httpd.conf` file. After that I installed phpmyadmin using

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Everything was working fine (i.e. phpmyadmin, mysql etc) After that I copied one of my projects to `/var/www/` and when I try to access this I keep getting this error:

> You don't have permission to access /AfaqTraders on this server.

I have tried

```
chmod -R o+w /var/www
```

to provide it the required (read write) permissions but I am still having this error and unable to get rid of it. Can any one please tell me what am I missing here. I am new to `Ubuntu` and don't know much about it, so apologize if any of this seems noob to you.

P.S. I have tried almost all of the questions here at askubuntu but wasn't able to get this to work.

Below is how my `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file looks:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    Require all denied 
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks        
        AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /*> 
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try add read for all, `chmod -R +r /var/www` , check if there any hidden .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the following command did, but it solved the problem  for me:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Comment: This command set the permission on all files and directories below `/var/www` to read, write & execute for the owner, read & execute for the group owner and the others. Directories must be executable, but files under this directory doesn't need it, except for CGI files. `sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and `sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

`AllowOverwrite` for `/var/www` should be `None` in stead of `All` ;)

Comment: Hi santa, when you give an answer, please explain why it should be as you mention. This way (even if the answer is right) there is little benefit for other users who might read the post.